# how can i use local base image in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I make a base Image file (Ex. file name: customblah)

and I make a Dockerfile:

```
FROM customblah
~~
CMD bin/bash
```

but, Dockerfile refer to docker registry.

this customblah image file is in local `./home/root`

How can i use this local image file?

I want to make Dockerfile using customblah base image.

Comment: Is customblah tagged? What error are you getting specifically?

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `docker images | grep customblah`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an image from your Dockerfile first.

```
docker build -t customblah .
```

That assumes you have your Dockerfile in the current directory.

After that you can run it like `docker run --rm -ti customblah` and you can as well reference it in builds as `FROM customblah`.

You can further tweak behaviour to ensure that you **only** use local images by using the `--pull` flag in your run commands with the value `never`